# Qt Multiple Types of Styles for an item (QLabel, QPushbutton, ...)

Tags: css, qt, qt-designer, qlabel

- I am designing a UI with Qt Creator 3.6.1
- I am using Qt designer    form.
- I have a QWidget which contains 20    QLabels.
- I want 10 of these       QLabels to have a red background color
  and the other 10 to have a     blue  background color.
- I want to use      css for this purpose.

I found out that you can style all QLabels in parent widget css which will style all labels.

```
QLabel
{
    background-color: red
}
```

However in my case I want two classes of styles.
Is there a way to do so by not styling each of the remaining 10 blue labels individually?

I know that I can style elements by name but that's a huge amount of effort.

Comment: Why not just change the palette for the labels? Call `setAutoFillBackground(true)` on the labels and set to a palette with the `QPalette::Window` role set. Use one palette for red, another for blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use CSS class you have to set a class name to your QLabels:

```
QLabel* redLabel = new QLabel("red label");
QLabel* blueLabel = new QLabel("blue label");

redLabel->setProperty("class","my-1st-class");
blueLabel->setProperty("class","my-2nd-class");
```

Then use your class names in your CSS file :

```
.my-1st-class{
     background-color: red;
}

.my-2nd-class{
     background-color: blue;
}
```